# C - manually parsing char* into integer

Tags: c, strings, parsing, integer

I'm trying to parse a `char*` into an `int` without using `atoi()`. I walk through the string, check if it's a valid digit, then add that digit to my integer by multiplying by 10 and adding the digit. I am not accepting negative integers.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define TRUE  1
#define FALSE 0

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc < 2)
        exit(1);


    char *p = argv[1];

    int amount = 0;
    int len = strlen((const char*) argv[1]); // calculate len beforehand
    int contin = TRUE;
    for (int i = 0; contin && i < len; ++i, ++p) {
        switch (*p) {
        case '0':
            amount = (amount * 10);
            break;
        case '1':
            amount = (amount * 10) + 1;
            break;
        case '2':
            amount = (amount * 10) + 2;
            break;
        case '3':
            amount = (amount * 10) + 3;
            break;
        case '4':
            amount = (amount * 10) + 4;
            break;
        case '5':
            amount = (amount * 10) + 5;
            break;
        case '6':
            amount = (amount * 10) + 6;
            break;
        case '7':
            amount = (amount * 10) + 7;
            break;
        case '8':
            amount = (amount * 10) + 8;
            break;
        case '9':
            amount = (amount * 10) + 9;
            break;
        default:
            contin = FALSE;
            break;
        }
    }

    fprintf(stdout, "amount: %i\n", amount);
    return 0;
}
```

...which works nicely. But, is there a better/more idiomatic way to do this?

**EDIT**: Thanks to Groo, I'm able to remove the giant switch statement:

````
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define TRUE  1
#define FALSE 0

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc < 2)
        exit(1);


    char *p = argv[1];

    int amount = 0;
    int len = strlen((const char*) argv[1]); // calculate len beforehand
    int contin = TRUE;
    for (int i = 0; contin && i < len; ++i, ++p) {
        /* handle negative integers */
        if (*p == '-' && i == 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "negative integers are invalid.\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        if (*p > 0x2F && *p < 0x3A)
            amount = (amount * 10) + (*p - '0');
        else {
            contin = FALSE;
            --p;
        }
    }

    fprintf(stdout, "amount: %i\n", amount);
    return 0;
}
```
````

Comment: I wouldn't use `0x2F` and `0x3A` because most people don't know ASCII by heart and because your intent is to compare then with the digits zero and nine. Use `'0'` and `'9'` -- it's easier to understand and better reflects the intent of the code.

Comment: Also note that every answer so far works because the integer value of numbers 0 to 9 are guaranteed by the C standard to be consecutive. There's no such guarantee for other characters, so you can not reliably do the same thing with hexadecimal digits.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Since [command line arguments are null-terminated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11020172/are-char-argv-arguments-in-main-null-terminated), we can avoid `strlen()` entirely by just running through the string until we hit `'\0'`; this also gets rid of `contin` and `i`
- `(*p > 0x2F && *p < 0x3A)` isn't very obvious, I'd just use `'0'` and `'9'` to make it easier to understand the intention and to be consistent with the rest of the code
- You could use `EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE` instead of `0` and `1` respectively
- For consistency, I'd replace your call to `exit()` with a simple `return`
- I'd remove the `amount:` part of the print; it should be clear from the context (running this program) what the output actually is; this would also make processing the output easier

Putting it all together, we end up with this short piece:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc < 2)
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    char *p = argv[1];
    int amount = 0;

    while (*p) {
        if (*p < '0')
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        if (*p > '9')
            return EXIT_FAILURE;

        amount = (amount * 10) + (*p++ - '0');
    }

    fprintf(stdout, "%i\n", amount);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Note, however, that this doesn't account for:

- negative numbers (starting with a `-`)
- positive numbers starting with a `+`
- any leading whitespace

Furthermore:

- If the input starts with a number and has a letter following sometimes later, it will `break` out and print the number it has found until then; but if the first character found is a letter, the program prints `0` and reports success, which could be by design, but could also be considered a bug
- The use of `*p++` can be a bit dangerous if this was code shared with less experienced programmers, as simply changing it to `++*p` would increase the *value* pointed to instead of the pointer itself; changing it to `*(p++)` might help
- While this comes down to taste, I would argue to *always* use curly braces, even for one-liners: otherwise, adding another line later would break the code; also consistency is a plus
- Adding support for leading whitespace is easy and also supports my previous point, as missing brackets would break the program:

```
    if (*p == ' ') {
        *p++;
        continue;
    }
```

- If you don't want to implement support for negative numbers, it might be reasonable to change the type of `amount` to `unsigned` or - even better - [`unsigned long long`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types), which would give you a possible range of [0, +18446744073709551615]
- Naive handling of negative integers would be quite easy to implement (but note [Roland's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/235825/216848) for caveats with this):

```
    int sign = 1;

    if (*p == '-') {
        sign = -1;
        *p++;
    }

    /* loop */

    amount *= sign;
```

Comment: yes, the part when the program stops when it encounters an invalid digit is intentional.

Comment: Why write EXIT_FAILURE twice in 2 if statements.? Why not `if (*p < '0' || *p > '9') EXIT_FAILURE`?

Comment: @OliverSchonrock both would be completely fine, as it shouldn't make a difference in performance. Personally, I find it easier to read and understand when they are separate, but that's really down to personal preference.

Comment: Sure, You're right that the ASM will be identical. I always aim for "least vertical space, while retaining readability". Being able to scan vertically on a finite height Monitor is crucial in understanding code. But you're right it is subjective. If you find `||` not clear, then sure.

Comment: @OliverSchonrock that makes sense. I guess it has become a habit for me to split  things into the smallest and simplest possible pieces. Regarding vertical space, you would most likely hate [the style that I use myself](https://pastebin.com/raw/wENKXpY6) in these situations (curly brackets for one-liner, each on its own line). Feel free to edit the code to your suggested variant, by the way.

Comment: Yeah, the whole "1 line if" discussion is highly subjective. You're right though, I do use one line ifs, especially for this kind of "early return" code where it is very unlikely someone wants to add a second line. Your answer is very good, it doesn't need editing. These are subjective discussion points. Your aversion to `||` was new to me, but there is nothing wrong with it.

Comment: Handling negative integers is not as easy as you think. There is one integer that is a valid negative number but an invalid positive number. For `int32_t` that is the number `-2147483648`.

Comment: Good point @RolandIllig - and on that note, I've completely left out the whole topic of overflow / handling big numbers. Maybe you can elaborate on that aspect some more in your answer.

Comment: As a learning example, printing the result is perfectly acceptable, but to be usable, the program should be a function returning the parsed int.

Answer (score 2):

What should the output be if I enter 123456789012345678901234567890? That's producing an integer overflow right now.

Comment: uh, I'm new, but shouldn't this be a comment? Just asking :)

Comment: correct, when I put this into my application I'll add code that will handle an overflow.

Comment: Granted, this answer is very short. It reveals a bug in your code though and thus might be considered a review. It's only meant as an addition to the other answer, though.

Comment: In this cases we can store the answer by taking this number modulo a prime number i.e $10^9 + 7$.

Comment: @strikersps, doesn't that just change program from Undefined Behaviour to one that produces a wrong answer?  It's hard to see how that would be an improvement.  You need a better strategy for dealing with overflow - I suggest it's better to return `EXIT_FAILURE`, since a number that's too large is the same category as one that's too small.